# Php select then subtract selected function

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to coding and only have the basic understanding for php. I am trying to perform this function which i am not sure how to do it. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks

The task:
To SELECT a set of data from table 1, then take away selected items from Table 2. (As items from Table 2 might also appear from table 1).

Example, i have a list of cars in table 1, after a user selected a car from Table 2(which might also exist in table 1) then the echoed result shows the result from table 1 minus the existed car from table 2.

And echo them in JSON.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: Can i write it like this?

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM car1 WHERE userid = '$userid' NOT IN (SELECT userid = '$userid2'From car2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "not in" clause of mysql. it should work.
c1 is car1 table and c2 is car2 table.

```
select c1.name,c2.name from car as c1 ,car2 as c2 where c2.id NOT IN('c1.id');
```

Comment: I just edited my question, wondering if i can write the query like that?

Answer (score 0):

mysql clause IN works like following

```
mysql_query("select * from car where car.id NOT IN(1,2,3)");
```

it will return those rows which row's id is not 1,2,3

Comment: Is it possible to have the NOT IN for variables that are not preset? What i mean is, there are 2 tables, i am trying to select the userid row from car1, and if that userid exist in Table 2 then i want to echo all the result from car1 excluding the ones that the userid that exist in table2. I am not sure how to write the query for it.